# Ubuntu 20.04 update error: 403 Sorry, not allowed to fetch that type of file

Tags: apt, updates, 20.04

I have an Ubuntu 18.04 server running apt-cacher (Version: 1.7.16) for our environment which is a mix of Ubuntu 16, 18 and 20 hosts.  Our Ubuntu 20.04 hosts are having trouble patching when using our apt-cacher host.  Patching direct to the internet works fine but it's against our policy.  I'm seeing ***not allowed to fetch that type of file*** errors:

```
admin7@template:~# apt-get update
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [107 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [98.3 kB]
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [107 kB]
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages [147 kB]
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main Translation-en [54.8 kB]
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata [3560 B]
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata [3560 B]
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata [3560 B]
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata [3560 B]
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata [3560 B]
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata [3560 B]
Ign:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata [2608 B]
Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata [2608 B]
Ign:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Err:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata
  403  Sorry, not allowed to fetch that type of file: caa2bcaedd682ba4d80d0710baf3d9fc5e451692820011530d55b767636e4c34 [IP: 10.1.2.3 3142]
Ign:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Err:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata
  403  Sorry, not allowed to fetch that type of file: 925b094241232d03a4765ecf2eadf174dfa8838476e49191e2f0d8e33980c953 [IP: 10.1.2.3 3142]
Get:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 Packages [89.4 kB]
Get:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main Translation-en [33.9 kB]
Get:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata [2384 B]
Get:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata [2384 B]
Get:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata [2384 B]
Get:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata [2384 B]
Get:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata [2384 B]
Get:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata [2384 B]
Ign:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign:27 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign:27 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign:27 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Err:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata
  403  Sorry, not allowed to fetch that type of file: 8d1b06044b073a6d834a31b177e3da5028e29170ea7aacab20143e2a516ee602 [IP: 10.1.2.3 3142]
Ign:27 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Fetched 312 kB in 2s (133 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/main/cnf/Commands-amd64  403  Sorry, not allowed to fetch that type of file: caa2bcaedd682ba4d80d0710baf3d9fc5e451692820011530d55b767636e4c34 [IP: 10.1.2.3 3142]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/universe/cnf/Commands-amd64  403  Sorry, not allowed to fetch that type of file: 925b094241232d03a4765ecf2eadf174dfa8838476e49191e2f0d8e33980c953 [IP: 10.1.2.3 3142]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/main/cnf/Commands-amd64  403  Sorry, not allowed to fetch that type of file: 8d1b06044b073a6d834a31b177e3da5028e29170ea7aacab20143e2a516ee602 [IP: 10.1.2.3 3142]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I've seen multiple posts complaining of similar issues and they are almost always resolved by editing the package_files_regexp setting.  However, those posts refer to a specific file extension.  In my case the problem files do not appear to have a particular file extension, just a long string of hexidecimal characters.  Also, those hex strings differ from file to file.  At this point I don't know the correct procedure on how to resolve this issue.  Is there way to edit the package_files_regexp so it allows these hexidecimal strings?

Answer (score 1):

I just solved this issue on my Ubuntu MATE 20.04 :

```
apt remove command-not-found
apt clean
apt auto-remove
apt install command-not-found
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made some progress.   The output from apt-get update states at the very end:

**Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.**

I went in to the apt-cacher config file and temporarily set:

index_files_regexp = ^(.*)

apt-get update now works on the Ubuntu 20.04 hosts.  I do not want to leave it set like this.  Still looking for the correct solution but at least I have a temporarily workaround.  I have verified the problem is the name of the index files and the apt-cacher configuration file is not set to allow some of those file names.